# Java 8 Lambdas - Bitwise AND Operations

Tags: java, for-loop, lambda, java-8, bitwise-operators

I'm currently tackling with the issue of transforming for loops which use bitwise operations using Lambdas in Java 8.

Given a set of complex entries, it's required for the loop to traverse ALL entries and call a given method on them (method returns boolean value). Afterwards, return the result.

In other words, I need to call the method on all entries and store the result. **The reason behind this is that each entry independently performs a complex operation and must be performed.** The end result is a combination of results.

Code snippet:

```
boolean areAllSuccessful = true;
for (SomeEntry entry : entries) {
     areAllSuccessful = areAllSuccessful & entry.doComplexAction(); // keep calling the method on other entries regardless of the result.
}

return areAllSuccessful;
```

The problem is that the Lambda Functions in Java 8 usually perform short-circuit operations (once the false entry has been detected, the "loop" breaks and the false result is returned).

My best solution so far was to use map/filter/count combination:

```
return entries
       .stream()
       .map(entry -> entry.doComplexAction())
       .filter(result -> result == false)
       .count() > 0
```

Is there a smarter/cleaner way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: (for example) http://www.concretepage.com/java/jdk-8/java-8-stream-allmatch-anymatch-nonematch-example ?

Comment: I think your use case is better suited for traditional `for` loops than for streams. Really, trying to make everything be stream-based is not the way to go. If it works as it is, then leave it that way.

Comment: Just a comment: `isSuccessful()` is a **really bad name** for a method with side-effects that makes lots of operations. You should 1) make clear in the question that the method has side-effects and thus needs to be called on every entry, and 2) rename the method to something like `doComplexActions()`.

Comment: Don't use side effects if you need streams XOR don't use streams if you need side-effects. Everything else is just asking for troubles.

Comment: that the called method has side effects, should be written more prominently (bold, blinking, in the title and whatever ;-)).

Comment: functional programing doesn't like functions with side effects much.

Comment: Don't use bitwise operations to avoid short circuiting. You could *easily* have just **reversed the order** (`entry.isSuccessful() && areAllSuccessful`) to force the method to execute. Don't use screwdrivers to hammer nails. You'll just confuse everyone. Also, don't put a long comment at the end of the line where it'll go off the screen and devs won't read it. Put it on its own line before the line it annotates.

Comment: Renamed isSuccessful to doComplexAction, as suggested.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Shouldn't that look something like this:

```
boolean areAllSuccessful = entries.stream()
   .map(entry -> entry.isSuccessful())
   .reduce(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean::logicalAnd);
```

Comment: …and then wait for the next developer seeing the code and saying “hey, that looks like the perfect task for `allMatch`”…

Comment: @Holger I accidentally thought about that too... looking at some code that has 3 fields in a constructor and only one being final. My initial reaction was to remove that final at all... sort of the same here. probably a code comment needed.

Comment: @Holger Bohemian just posted an answer using `allMatch`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42277670/

Comment: I find it a bit disturbing to have `Boolean::logicalAnd`, yet still `entry -> entry.isSuccessful()`. Can't the latter be written `SomeEntry::isSuccessful`?

Answer (score 21):

The neatest, and most efficient, way is to use a method reference with `allMatch()`

```
return entries.stream().allMatch(SomeEntry::isSuccessful);
```

If you have 1000's of elements, consider using `parallelStream()` instead.

This doesn't process every element (it returns at the first `false`), so if your `isSuccessful()` method has side effects, it's a bad name and you should rename it or refactor the code to perform the side effects in a `process()` (or similar) method and have `isSuccessful()` return the result, throwing an `IllegalStateException` if `process()` hasn't first been called.

If you don't refactor, some developer (including you) will call `isSuccessful()` without realising it "does stuff", which could be bad.

Comment: that's the point, the OP does not want to stop at the first false. That's what he said in a comment : *Actually I've hidden the problem a bit. The operations behind the isSuccessful() calls are actually complex independent system actions and should be performed regardless of each other. The end result is a combination of all responses*

Comment: regardless of the side notes (comments) this is very helpfull for otheres (like me) comming across this.

Comment: My answer explained the `allMatch()` solution, and my comments explained how bad a name like `isSuccessful()` really is. But your answer explains both and is clearer. +1.

Answer (score 11):

You don't really need `map()` if you're going to use `count()`:

```
return !(entries
        .stream()
        .filter(entry -> !entry.isSuccessful())
        .count() > 0);
```

---

*If* the method `isSuccessful()` didn't have side-effects, and all you needed to know was if all the entries were successful, you could have used `allMatch()`:

```
return entries
        .stream()
        .allMatch(entry -> entry.isSuccessful());
```

This is indeed a short-circuit operation that will return `false` as soon as it finds an entry where `isSuccessful()` is `false`, not consuming the whole stream unless necessary. But you already commented that `isSuccesful()` really means "do some complex actions and *then* tell me if they were successful", so it doesn't apply.

Comment: what bothers me is the comment : `keep calling the method on other entries regardless of the result`; allMatch will stop processing elements as soon as it finds the first that is not matched.

Comment: @Eugene yeah, I just noticed that. It's weird, though, because in the example, processing all elements is clearly not needed, nor would it be with a bitwise OR either.

Comment: Actually I've hidden the problem a bit. The operations behind the isSuccessful() calls are actually complex independent system actions and should be performed regardless of each other. The end result is a combination of all responses.

Comment: @xanmcgregor Oh, I see. Well, so much for my last edit :D I'll get back to my first answer then!